# Как залить несколько проектов на GitHub

Tags: github

Ребята, пыталась залить второй проект, но не получилось. пользовалась этой инструкцией:

```
Использовать папки-поддиректории:

nickname.github.io - корневая директория сайта (главная страница)
nickname.github.io/site 1/ - поддиректория 1 (папка сайта 1)
nickname.github.io/site 2/ - поддиректория 2 (папка сайта 2)
nickname.github.io/site 3/ - поддиректория 3 (папка сайта 3)
```

но все равно не получается, подскажите что не так?

Comment: Подкаталоги не пустые, файлы есть?

Comment: ,конечно не пустые. я сайт залила с папками и со всем что мне нужно, но все равно( главная страница открывается, а папка сайта 1 - нет

Comment: ***Как*** не получилось, какое сообщение об ошибке или что происходит?

Comment: Никакой ошибки не выдает, когда хочу перейти по ссылке на сайт, то просто выдает результаты поиска в гугле. я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: @Kromster, теперь выдает ошибку "File not found

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file."

Comment: Уточню — у вас в названии папки/адреса пробел? Проверьте черз сам репозиторий гитхаба, чтобы файлы были на сервере.

Answer (score 3):

Для решение проблемы нужно выбрать Settings-GitHub Pages-Source-master branch